# svn : How to split a large commit into several small commits?

Tags: svn, commit, subversive

I have created a new repository for a project and am adding some exisiting code base (llvm) to it. This code base is about 18,000 files which is making the my initial commit take lots of time. (read 5 hours)

Is there a way to split this HUGE commit into several smaller commits? So that it can complete faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When seeding a new repository with a large number of files, I *highly* recommend using an `svn import` command from the *server* instead of committing the files from a remote machine.  The easiest way to do this is:

1. Bundle up the code into a single archive (using gzip, 7zip, etc)
2. Transfer that archive to the server (using rsync, scp, etc)
3. Log into the server remotely
4. Decompress the archive into a temp directory
5. Use `svn import` to seed the repository

This will prove to be significantly faster in most cases.  Transferring a single large archive over the network is typically much faster than transferring many smaller files, even if you don't take compression into account.  The performance difference is significantly larger using Windows.  Certain versions of Subversion have a Windows bug that causes each file to open and close a separate network connection, which adds a significant amount of overhead compared to using a single network connection for the entire operation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a case when smaller commits may matter:

- repo is served over http by Apache's mod_dav_svn
- path-based authorization is in use
- [`SVNPathAuthz short_circuit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.mod_dav_svn.conf.html) is not set

Comment: I was facing a very slow performance in svn log and this posted pointed me to the solution! As the documentation says, "All of this path checking can sometimes be quite expensive, especially in the case of svn log" on http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.pathauthzoff  - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can split a commit by specifying individual files. However, this is not likely to make it go faster: you still have to move the files over the network, and write them to disk. In fact, it's quite possible that it will go slower, as Subversion needs to lock the repository at some point in an update (so that it can assign a unique revision number).

I think you'd be better off creating the repository on your local disk, doing the commit there (which eliminates network overhead), and then pushing the repository to its final destination.

Comment: Incidentally, I just timed adding 1,000 8k files to a repository on a local machine. Total was 1 minute (22 seconds to add, 38 seconds to commit). It scaled almost linearly from 100 files. So I think your 5 hours indicates some sort of a network problem.

Comment: Your observation is  correct. I am committing to codeplex, which seems to be giving me a upload speed of about 10KB/s (my upper cap for bandwidth is much much higher). Guess i should commit to some other host.

Answer (score 1):

Going with smaller chunks might not result in decrease of total time spent.

When taking into account process startup, teardown and communication overhead, **several smaller commits will probably take more in total time spent** when compared to a single huge commit.

You did not state which operating system is being used but how about installing [SVN Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and cherry-picking as much files necessary for each commit? At any rate, SVN is directory based, so if your 18,000 files are in separate directories then by all means, commit each directory separately.

Here are a couple links in case using command line is an option:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html